# disable the button

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nscalendar

I have some 6 `UILabels` which will show the date like below:

```
                    Jan,2016 (label)
   (button)  < **27Dec 28Dec 29Dec 30Dec 31Dec 1Jan** >(Button)
```

Also I am having two arrow `UIButton` at both side when user can move to back date or previous date. And i have one lable to show the current month based on my date showing

Here is my full code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    firstdate = [NSDate date];
    firstdate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:-(5*86400) sinceDate:firstdate];
    [self dateChange];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM,yyyy"];  dateLabel.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    dateLabel.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate: firstdate];   
}

-(void)dateChange
{
    NSArray *labelArray = @[flabel, slabel, tlabel, folabel, fivlabel,sixlabel];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"ddMMM";
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        NSDate *nextDate = [calendar dateByAddingUnit: NSCalendarUnitDay value:i toDate:firstdate options:nil];
        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)labelArray[i];
        label.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextDate];

        if (i==5) {
            dateFormatter.dateFormat=@"MMM,yyyy";
            dateLabel.text = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextDate] capitalizedString];
        } 
    } 
}
- (IBAction)calRight:(id)sender {
    firstdate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:86400 sinceDate:firstdate];
    [self dateChange];
}

- (IBAction)calLeft:(id)sender {

    firstdate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:-86400 sinceDate:firstdate];
    [self dateChange];
}
```

So what I need in .For example like says -  today is `Jan 1` .so if user open my app they will see`Jan 1` at `last date` followed by previous `december date` at back like I mention above .

So in that case if user on `current date`means like `Jan1` means then my `Rightbutton`should be `disabled`. At the same time when user use `left button` to go `november month` menas then my `right button`should be `enabled`

Only my `rightbutton`should be `disabled` when user in `current date`.
Please help me to solve I have an idea that !

```
if (some condition) 
    [leftBtn setEnabled:NO];
 else
    [leftBtn setEnabled:YES];
```

But I am not sure about condition and code.

Comment: **Never** use 86400 seconds to do date math. Use the appropriate methods of `NSCalendar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your method dateChange with bellow code and also btnRight is your right side button so change name whatever you have give for it.

```
-(void)dateChange
{
    NSArray *labelArray = @[flabel, slabel, tlabel, folabel, fivlabel,sixlabel];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"ddMMM";
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < labelArray.count; ++i) {

        NSDate *nextDate = [calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:i toDate:firstdate options:nil];
        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)labelArray[i];
        label.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextDate];

        if (i==(labelArray.count-1)) {
            dateFormatter.dateFormat=@"MMM,yyyy";
            dateLabel.text = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextDate] capitalizedString];

            NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

            if ([[dateFormat stringFromDate:nextDate] isEqualToString:[dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]])
               btnRight.enabled = false; //It's the same day
            else
               btnRight.enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no disable are performing ...I am moving to `Jan 2 `. So actually as per my question its should be disabled

Comment: And also my month label also not working well as per your solution bro

Comment: ALSO my month label is showing wrongly.. When first time i open even though todays date is `JAN1` its showing` December,2015`

Comment: Again i tried with 7 labels but i am not getting correct date.Hers is that link please help me    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34584495/date-not-showing-in-correct-manner

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];//You Can Change Date Format
    NSString *strDate=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    [btnYourButton setEnabled:([strDate isEqualToString:txtYourTextFieldDate.text])?NO:YES];
```

Comment: My button is working, now is` Jan1` . So if press Left button its going to `Jan2`. Actually i should not go to `Jan2`

Answer (score 0):

`NSCalendar` has a very convenient method to check if today contains a specific date.

```
rightButton.enabled = ![[NSCalendar currentCalendar] isDateInToday:aDate];
```

---

**Important note:**

## **Never ever do date math using the 86400 constant**

Consider that on a day where daylight saving time changes a day doesn't have 86400 seconds.

For example instead of

```
firstdate = [NSDate date];
firstdate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:-(5*86400) sinceDate:firstdate];
```

write

```
firstdate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:-5 toDate:[NSDate date] options:nil];
```

Comment: My button is working, now is` Jan1` . So if press Left button its going to Jan2. Actually i should not go to Jan2

Comment: ok about 86400.. But about my question. ?? My button is not still disable